# How somebody can access images once they’re uploaded to Imgur via Imgur’s API

Tags: post, https, imgur

I’m currently using Imgur’s api (https://apidocs.imgur.com/#c85c9dfc-7487-4de2-9ecd-66f727cf3139) to automatically upload my image and get url of it.

Just out of curiosity is there any other way of accessing the publicly uploaded image file other than via its URL?

I tried searching for the id given as a response after making the POST request (Imgur’s upload api works with the POST request) on Imgur’s website and I couldn’t find any.